# flutter: pop rewrite parameters I gave to page

Tags: flutter

Page1:

```
Map a={};
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
    return Page2(a: a);
}));
```

Page2:

```
a['test']=1;
Navigator.pop(context);
```

after pop, I print(a) on Page1 and the value is {"test":1}
how can I prevent this problem?
as I expect a should be empty Map {}

I have no idea about how it work

Answer (score 1):

If 'a' is a global variable, this is the expected output.

```
a['test']=1;
Navigator.pop(context);
```

In this section, you just set 'a' with a key 'test' and a value of 1. The given value would remain the same even after popping back. Therefore your print result is {"test":1}.

Try using different names like 'a1', 'a2' or private variables.